# Thinking of a vector field as a 2-covector

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question about [this](https://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/Lect1.pdf) document.

On pg 1, it says that the vector field $B$, which stands for the magnetic field, can be thought of as a $2$- form on $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ $$F=\frac{1}{2\pi r^3}(x_1dx^2\wedge dx^3+\text{ cyclic})$$ How can a vector field be thought of as a $2$ form? Is there some kind of duality going on here?

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can associate (n-1)-form $\beta$ with a vector field $B$ by the condition that for all 1-forms $\alpha$ the following equality holds:
$$ \alpha \wedge \beta = \langle \alpha, B\rangle {\rm vol} $$
where $\langle \alpha, B\rangle$ is the evaluation of 1-form $\alpha$ on vector field $B$, and ${\rm vol}={\rm d}x^1\wedge {\rm d}x^2\wedge\dots\wedge {\rm d}x^n$ is the standard volume form in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This operation can be defined on any manifold with a distinguished volume form.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that $\beta = \star B$, when B is seen as a 1-form. Here, $\star$ is the hodge star operator.